# Touch (not click) listener

Tags: ontouchlistener

Last two days I'm trying to write simple drag and drop functionality in Android API7 but all of the time I have problem. Now with touch listener. I use onTouchListener but onTouch method it's call only when I press screen on UI element. When I press screen in another place and then I move my finger above element with specified onTouchListener nothing happend . Why? 
Is available any listener for android  which lets catch touch event without click on screen in place where UI element is located ?  Thanx for help because I'm going crazy today ;)

Answer (score 0):

onTouchListener is using for views only. U can use it for any layout (LinearLayout for ex). It will works for all your screen, if your layout with "fill_parent" parameters. Also u need to control your ACTION_DOWN, UP and MOVE parameters. Maybe this sample helps u:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class main extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout ll =(LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.ll);
    ll.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    int action=event.getAction();
    StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();
    str.append("\nActrion type: ");

    switch(action)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: str.append(«ACTION_DOWN\n»);break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: str.append(«ACTION_MOVE\n»);break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: str.append(«ACTION_UP\n»);break;
    }

    Log.v(«Mytag», str.toString());
    return true;
}
}
```