# Drag/Hold/Enter another TextView Boundaries?

Tags: android

I have some TextView and want their background turn red when the finger move/hit/enter their boundaries after ACTION_DOWN occur.

I tried it with on touch down listener but it doesn't work, because after click (Only trigger ACTION_DOWN) one of the TextView and drag it, the rest of the TextView doesn't turn red (only the first one, where ACTION_DOWN occur is turning into red background). I attach all of TextView to OnTouch listener and also tried ACTION_MOVE, but still no result.

Anyone can help? Thanks.

similar to this problem [Touch (not click) listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867333/touch-not-click-listener)

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (selectMode == 0) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }else{
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (selectMode == 0) {
                selectMode = 1;
            }else{
                selectMode = 0;
            }
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How many textviews do you have ? I couldn't understand your question. Plase, provide the XML layout

Comment: Are you trying to implement button functionality?  turn red when the finger move/hit/enter their boundaries. If you want your view to react on your finger - you have to know what boundaries are. Then attack a touch listener to your view and track the positiion of you finger. As soon as finger coords inside boundaries - turn the thing RED. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, that is what I'm trying to do. I already found the solution, Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
Rect outRect = new Rect();
int[] location = new int[2];

// Attach all of the TextView to the onTouch listener
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // get the event x and y coordinate
    int x = (int) event.getRawX();
    int y = (int) event.getRawY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // My viewArray is list of TextView that I want to check that the "touch" hit/enter the TextView area
            for (int i = 0; i < viewArray.length; i++) {
                // Get the area of TextView
                viewArray[i].getDrawingRect(outRect);
                // Get the location of TextView 
                viewArray[i].getLocationOnScreen(location);
                // Move the outRect to the TextView location
                outRect.offset(location[0], location[1]);
                // Check if the "touch" collide with the TextView area (outRect)
                if (outRect.contains(x, y)){
                    if (selectMode == 0) {
                        viewArray[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    } else {
                        viewArray[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (selectMode == 0) {
                selectMode = 1;
            }else{
                selectMode = 0;
            }
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```